# Create select field with list of values in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, select

I've added the following into my form-login.php

```
<p class="form-row form-row-wide">
                <label for=age">Age </label>
                <select type="text" class="input-text" name="age" id="age" value="<?php if ( ! empty( $_POST['age'] ) ) esc_attr_e( $_POST['age'] ); ?>" class="regular-text" /><br />
                </p>
```

and this to my functions.php

```
 if ( isset( $_POST[''age'] ) ) {
        update_user_meta( $customer_id, ''age', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['age'] ) );
    }
```

I've got a vague idea of how to populate the select field with data via JSON but I have no idea where I would add this file to make it render the value and then pass the chosen value to the database.

I'm hoping someone can point me in the right direction.

Thanks,
Dan

Comment: Do you need to populate the age values dinamically? Why not hardcode the values or generate from a for loop over a range of values?

Comment: Whatever is easier I guess. How would I hardcode the values so that when one is selected it will save that value to the database?

Comment: If your list of ages is fixed, you simply need to add `<option value="18">18</option>` under the `<select>`. They will be available on the page and sent to the backend together with the rest of the form.